# AngularJS + TypeScript + Restangular injection

Tags: angularjs, typescript, restangular

I have problem with setting up `angularjs + typescript` application with `restangular` plugin

Steps I have done:

1. `bower install --save restangular`
   (now I have in index.html 
   `<script src="bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js"></script>`)
2. add `restangular` to app dependencies

   `angular.module('myapp', [
       'ngAnimate',
       'ngCookies',
       'ngResource',
       'ngRoute',
       'ngSanitize',
       'ngTouch',
       'restangular'
     ])`
3. Install typings for restangular
4. Now I'm trying to set up restangular:

   `/// <reference path="../../typings/restangular/restangular.d.ts" />
   ...
   angular.module('myapp').config(($restangularProvider:restangular.IProvider) => {
      $restangularProvider.setBaseUrl("http://localhost:1337/");
   });`

The problem is that my browser throws error because it cannot resolve `$restangularProvider` dependency.

What I am doing wrong? I must forgot about something

Thanks

Comment: The error means that it can't find a provider named $restangular. According to the documentation it isn't '$restangularProvider', but 'RestangularProvider'

Answer (score 0):

I have figured to fix this issue by adding dependencies directly to `config` function like this:

```
.config(['RestangularProvider',
  (RestangularProvider: restangular.IProvider) => {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl("http://localhost:1337/");
  }]);
```